# Function$ f(-x)$ which is $x^2$ and how is it calculated

Tags: functions

I have one crucial question.

If you have $f(x)=x^2$ and then you make $f(-x)$

is it: $-(x^2)$ or $(-x)^2$

I think it should be $-(x^2)$, because we take argument as a whole and then make it negative. Thx

Comment: Just try it with $x=3$. What is $f(-3)$? Is it $-9$ or $9$?

Comment: The other way around, You first take the inverse with respect to addition and then square it, as You see these operations don't commute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only make $x$ negative when you calculate $f(-x)$. Since $f(x)=(x)^2$, you should have $f(-x)=(-x)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$-x^2$ would be $-(x^2) = -f(x)$.  On the other hand, $f(-x) = (-x)^2=x^2$.

Think of the recipe for $f(x)$ as "$f$ of a thing is that thing squared."  That's literally what $f(x)=x^2$ means.  So, $f(-x)$ must mean the square of $-x$, not the negative of $x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Think of making something negative as a function. Assume $g(x)=-x$. We can see that-
$$f(-x)=f(g(x))=g(x)^2=(-x)^2=x^2$$
The think about functions is that you start working from the inside.

The meaning of $f(-x)$ is asking what happens when I put the value of $-x$ for the function of $f$?

Thus, at the value $n=-x$, we must have-
$$f(n)=n^2=(-x)^2 \implies f(x)=(-x)^2$$

These functions cannot be applied in any order (commutativity doesn't exist). It matters in which order you use them. The negative must remain within the input value of $f$.